# React unmount component on window unload

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am rendering to the DOM with ReactDOM. I would like to know whether I have to manually unmount React components on window `unload` events. If so, what is the best practice here? What I can think of is the following:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructure(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleUnload = this.handleUnload.bind(this);
  }

  handleUnload() {
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(this.getDomNode());
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.handleUnload);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.handleUnload);
  }

  ...
}
```

Please advice, and thanks.

Comment: no, everything is destroyed when the page unloads anyway.

Comment: @dandavis that is only true for the top-level page. It's not destroyed, when the page is inside an iFrame. In that case, unmounting may make sense.

Answer (score 0):

According to another question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61409868/892874), React does not bother unmounting components when the page unloads. So yes, if you want this to happen, it would need to be done manually. I think what you have is the best way to do this.

However, depending on your requirements, I suspect best practise would be to clearly define what needs to happen on unmount and unload like this (rather than blindly unmount the component along with all its children, which could do a lot of unnecessary work):

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructure(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleUnload = this.handleUnload.bind(this);
  }

  handleUnloadOrWillUnmount() {
    // Do whatever you need when the component is unmounted
    // or the page is unloaded here
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    window.addEventListener(
        'beforeunload',
        this.handleUnloadOrWillUnmount,
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener(
        'beforeunload',
        this.handleUnloadOrWillUnmount,
    );
    this.handleUnloadOrWillUnmount();
  }

  ...
}
```