# Why doesn't componentWillUnmount trigger when closing the window?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

One would think that [`componentWillUnmount()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount) in react would trigger when closing the application. According to the docs, `componentWillUnmount()` is triggered when unmounting it or if it's relative component is being destroyed. *Why doesn't closing the window or tab unmount the component?*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

React would do that if it could, but think about it: closing the browser window means discarding all of the HTML, CSS, and JS on the page. Even if it tapped into the `onbeforeunload` event, it would be a waste to go about unmounting every component when they are about to be discarded anyway, and it would slow down closing the page. There historically hasn't been a good way to run any code when the tab is closed.

However, there is an *experimental* API called the [Beacon API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API) that attempts to solve this problem, in the case that you want to send data over the network when the browser is closed.

Comment: That makes sense. What would then be a use case for the component will unmount? There's a lot out there on lifecycle methods, but not many *use cases* that demonstrate this lifecycles' necessity.

Comment: Say you've got a component that fetches some data in a `setInterval` handler every so often. When the component unmounts you want that to stop, and `componentWillUnmount` is the best place to call `clearInterval`.

Answer (score 6):

The [**Mounting** term](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#lifecycle-methods) refers to actions on the DOM.

> Lifecycle methods are custom functionality that gets executed during the different phases of a component. **There are methods** available when the component gets created and inserted into the DOM (**mounting**), when the component updates, and when the component gets **unmounted** or removed from the DOM.

Closing the window/tab fires the browser [`onbeforeunload` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload):

> These events fire when a window is about to unload its resources.

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) { ... });
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) { ... };
```