# how do i activate an API when closing the browser? (react)

Tags: reactjs

I've applied 'componentWillUnmount' to save the customized width of each column of tables. it works well when leaving the page. However, when the user closes the browser, it does not work at all.

I am wondering if there is a way to send an API when closing the browser in react.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

componentWillUnmount refers to a virtual DOM event.
you can listen to a window event instead, see this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61409821/17130691)

Event then this is not reliable since web browsers can immediately shut down if a laptop ran out of battery for example.

I don't know you situation but maybe you would want to establish a socket connection to your backend to determent whether the connection is a live or not.

Comment: thx a lot! I've solved this issue~~